# can't find the css class to change width on jqueryUI selectmenu

Tags: jquery-ui, select-menu, jquery-ui-selectmenu

Using jqueryUI selectmenu plugin.

I can't find the right class to modify the width of the dropdown menu.  I can't figure out what css class has made the menu shorter that and select element above it.  Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Can you post your code or a jsFiddle example
?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using my Selectmenu fork (https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/tree/selectmenu) you need to use option menuWidth. Please note you need to set a width in any way, via an option or by using CSS. Auto width is not supported!

Please see the wiki for more info: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu